# Python subprocesses

Tags: python, subprocess

I have to create two functions and I'm struggling with both of them. The first function is to use a subprocess to run the `du -d 1` command of a target directory and return it to a list with out new line characters.

```py
def call_du_sub(location):
    du = " du -d 1 -h"
    subprocess.Popen(du, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The second function, where I don't know where to begin is to take the list created from the previous function and accept two arguments. Percent and total chars and return a bar graph as a string.

Comment: Your function does not create a list. It returns `None`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to have it create a list, I'm learning python and I'm lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample solution. A lot of things going on in it.

- For the `subprocess.Popen` call, I have:

  - dropped the `-h` switch of `du` because in this case it would only get in our way
  - dropped the `shell=True` and replaced the command string with a list, which is the preferred way to call a subprocess if you don't specifically need the shell's features
  - used the `communicate` method to retrieve stderr and stdout of the process, then discarded stderr, decoded stdout and returned it as a list of lines
- In the `bar_graph` function, I have:

  - converted the list of lines to a dictionary mapping directory name to the corresponding value returned by `du`, and converted that value to `float`
  - taken the value for `location` to use as the total to divide by, then removed it from the dictionary because we don't want to display that because if would distort our graph
  - created a dictionary mapping directory names to percentages
  - for each directory, printed a number of rectangles based on the corresponding percentage

```py
from pprint import pprint
import subprocess


def du(location: str):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["du", "-d", "1", location], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, _ = p.communicate()
    return out.decode().splitlines()


def bar_graph(du_output: list, location: str):
    du_dict = {key: float(value)
               for value, key
               in map(lambda line: line.split("\t"), du_output)}

    total_value = du_dict[location]
    del du_dict[location]

    name_width = max(len(key) for key in du_dict.keys())
    percentages = {key: value/total_value*100
                   for key, value
                   in du_dict.items()}
    print("--------------------------")
    print("percentages:")
    pprint(percentages)
    print("--------------------------")
    print("bar graph:")
    for key in sorted(percentages.keys()):
        value = round(percentages[key])
        print(f"{key:{name_width}}: {value:3d}% {'█'*round(value)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    location = "/some_dir"
    du_output = du(location)
    print("--------------------------")
    print("du_output:")
    pprint(du_output)

    bar_graph(du_output, location)
```

Output:

```
--------------------------
du_output:
['1627916\t/some_dir/some_subdir_3',
 '52379384\t/some_dir/some_subdir_1',
 '5736420\t/some_dir/some_subdir_2',
 '16\t/some_dir/lost+found',
 '59743740\t/some_dir']
--------------------------
percentages:
{'/some_dir/some_subdir_1': 87.67342653807746,
 '/some_dir/some_subdir_2': 9.601708898706375,
 '/some_dir/some_subdir_3': 2.724831086905507,
 '/some_dir/lost+found': 2.6781048524916585e-05}
--------------------------
bar graph:
/some_dir/some_subdir_1:  88% ████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
/some_dir/some_subdir_2:  10% ██████████
/some_dir/some_subdir_3:   3% ███
/some_dir/lost+found   :   0%
```